# Waiting for two asynchonous requests

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, xdomainrequest

I'm having trouble sending two request in PHP and waiting for both answers. Here is my code :

```
        function getXDomainRequest() {
            var xdr = null;

            if (window.XDomainRequest) {
                xdr = new XDomainRequest();
            } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xdr = new XMLHttpRequest({mozSystem: true});
            } else {
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX");
            }

            return xdr;
        }

        function sendData() {
            var json1= "";
            var json2= "";

            var xdr = getXDomainRequest();
            xdr.onload = function() {
                json1 = xdr.responseText;
            }

            var xdr2 = getXDomainRequest();
            xdr2.onload = function() {
                json2 = xdr2.responseText;
            }

            var Id = document.querySelector('#searchField').value;
            // Call API
            xdr.open("GET", "./dorequest.php?id=" + Id + "&requesttype=player");
            xdr.send();

            xdr2.open("GET", "./dorequest.php?id=" + Id + "&requesttype=stats");
            xdr2.send();

            xdr.wait();
            // Display results
            getHtmlResults(jsonPlayer, jsonStats);
        }
```

As expected here the `json1` and `json2` are still empty when `getHtmlResults` is called. I could do it synchronously by calling the `xdr2.send()` into the `xdr.onload` and my final function in the `xdr2.onload` but I want to do it asynchronously to get a better response time.

Thanks !

(any other comment on the code is welcome I'm quite new to php :) )

**EDIT :**

So I tryied using Ajax and it seems to work :)

```
            var jsonPlayer = "";
            var jsonStats = "";
            var steamId = document.querySelector('#searchField').value;
            $.when(
                $.ajax({url: "./dorequest.php?steamid=" + steamId + "&requesttype=playersummary",
                        success: function(response){ jsonPlayer = response; }}),
                $.ajax({url: "./dorequest.php?steamid=" + steamId + "&requesttype=csgostats",
                        success: function(response){ jsonStats = response; }}) ).done(
                function(player, stats) {
                            getHtmlResults(player, stats);
                        });
```

Comment: That's _Javascript_, not PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Promises** are commonly used as an abstraction to deal with asynchronous processes.

Wrap your AJAX calls in a Promise to do:

```
var ajax1 = request("stats");
var ajax2 = request("player");
when(ajax1, ajax2).done(function (stats, player) {
    console.log(stats, player);
});
```

Most popular frameworks have a built-in [Promise](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A) API.

Answer (score 0):

You can send both the calls ASync and have a function in both .onload which checks if the other request has completed. So as soon as one of the onload finds that the other onload is done, you can call the getHtmlResults function.